# Zip files with embedded script (self-extracting zipfiles, springboot fully executable jar), Any format specification?

Tags: java, spring-boot, zip

It's a rather old trick to embed a zip/tgz file to a shell script to make it self extracting, Springboot creates a fully executable jar, again using the same technique it's a shell script appended by the jar payload.

It's all good, but what I find it mind blowing is that the file is still a zip file, I can list the content of it with `zipinfo -1`,  so zipinfo had to ignore the script at the top of the file.

What's this format specification?

I know if I run `sed -e '1,/^exit/ !d' <file>` I am able to extract the script part, but is this some standard? I don't see delimiters to indicate where the payload starts

Furthermore not all tools implements this format, namely IBM java does not like it.